# Form submitting, even when AJAX form check returns false

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I have a really simple login form that I want to check if the credentials are right (so I don't have to reload a page if the credentials are wrong) before submitting the form.
The problem I'm running into is the response from the AJAX call. When the program decides that the user has supplied the correct credentials, this code works like a charm. In addition, when performing the two checks *prior* to the AJAX call (whether the user filled in the password input field or if the username is valid), the code works perfectly. It returns an error message and returns the false boolean value, preventing the form from submitting. But, when the response from the server comes back and it is found that the credentials *are not* correct, the error message displays, *but the page also reloads* (therein displaying an additional error message). Why is the form still submitting, even though I'm returning false? I've checked the JavaScript console, there are no errors. I've also tried inverting the `if` statement, checking if `ajax.responseText === "true"`, to the same result. I've tried adding a return false beneath the `ajax.onreadystatechange` call, but that just prevents the form from submitting at all (regardless of the response from the server).
Here is the form code:

```
<form method="POST" action="/afton/" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type='text' id='username' name='username' placeholder='Enter username...' required>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type='password' id='password' name='password' placeholder='Enter password...' required>
    <div class="form-buttons">
        <button type='submit' name='action' id="loginButton" value='login'>Login</button>
        <button type='button' id='register'>Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the js function:

```
// Function that checks whether the user supplied correct credentials
function checkForm() {

// Get the password provided and the server message div on the page
    const messageBox = document.getElementById("server-message");
    const password = document.getElementById("password").value;

// If password is blank, return error message and return false
    if (password === "") {
        messageBox.innerHTML = "<p class='badMessage'>Please fill in the password!</p>"
        return false;
    }

// If the username input tag doesn't contain the 'goodBorder' class received upon validation of username, return error and false
    if (!usernameInput.classList.contains("goodBorder")) {
        messageBox.innerHTML = "<p class='badMessage'>Please provide a valid username!</p>"
        return false;
    }

// AJAX call that posts the info via JSON to check
    const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "index.php?action=ajaxLogCheck", true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    ajax.send(JSON.stringify({"username":usernameInput.value, "password":password}));

// Handles the AJAX response
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200) {
            if (ajax.responseText !== "true") {
                messageBox.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                return false;
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `PHP` code that handles the `AJAX`:

```
// Get posted JSON encoded data
    $data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents("php://input")), true);

// Filter and sanitize the supplied username and password
    $username = filter_var($data['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_var($data['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

// Get user data by the username and check the username against the password
    $userData = getClient($username);
    $hashCheck = password_verify($password, $userData['password']);

// Check response from the hashCheck and return the result
    if ($hashCheck) {
        echo "true";
        exit;
    }
    logAtt($username, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], false, getBrowser($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
    sleep(0.5);
    $rands = array("Sorry, the username and/or password doesn't match our database. Please try again.", "Sorry, we don't recognize those login credentials. Please try again.", "Sorry, that login was incorrect. Please try again.", "Incorrect, please try again");
    $randResult = array_rand(array_flip($rands));
    echo "<p class='badMessage'>$randResult</p>";
```

Comment: where is `usernameInput` defined? Also - more importantly you know that the `a` in AJAX stands for `asynchronous`? The result from the ajax request is not guaranteed to return before the end of the function that called it??

Comment: @RamRaider at the top of the full JavaScript file. It is used in another function as well

Comment: ok - but  are you hoping to use the return value of the ajax request as a control to submit the form or not?

Comment: Where is your `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: @RamRaider yes, I'm trying to prevent the form from submitting if the return value is false

Comment: @miknik I was under the impression that that was the whole point of doing the `onsubmit = return checkForm()` that was the `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: I think you may not be able to use this methodology to accomplish your goals  - ajax is asynchronous by definition and you cannot return ( there are workarounds perhaps ) a value from an ajax call like this hoping to get the response from the server before the function itself terminates. You might have better luck with `Promises` which would allow the use of the `Fetch` api ~ the successor to XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @RamRaider I was afraid it had something to do with the asynchronous nature of `AJAX`...off to fetch!!

Comment: Your last true and false statements are within their own function `ajax.onreadystatechange = function ()` so they exit execution and return to the function caller, which is your main function. They don't exit that function or return a value for it.

Comment: @miknik I didn't even realize that!! How do I then return that boolean value to the main function??

Comment: You can't return anything from an async function in javascript, you have to use a callback or promise function. Your ajax code runs but its asynchronous so it doesn't then stop and wait for the response before moving on and executing the code below it. I don't really understand your workflow anyway. You would normally use `onsubmit = return checkForm()` to perform some client side validation before submitting. You are submitting via ajax within that function so why would you want to return true, as this will just submit the form again with a page reload

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Just the point in AJAX function where you were returning True or
        // False...Just Assign RESULT = 0 for False and 
        // RESULT = 1 for True
        // .....SUppose You password matches so you were returning True..
        // Dont do that...Instead Just Assign RESULT = 0 in that place and 
        // and out of the ajax Block paste this 'return Boolean(RESULT)'
        // if RESULT = 0 then it will return False else it will return True
// Function that checks whether the user supplied correct credentials
function checkForm()
    {
        // Initialize a Variable Here Say RESULT
        var RESULT = 0;
        if (password === "") 
            {
                 RESULT = 0;
            }
        else if (!usernameInput.classList.contains("goodBorder")) 
            {
                messageBox.innerHTML = "<p class='badMessage'>Please provide a valid username!</p>"
                RESULT = 0;
            }
        // After this Put the ajax function and if you want to return False
        // then simply assign RESULT = 0 instead of 'return false' else assign
        // RESULT = 1 instead of 'return true'

        return Booelan(RESULT); 
        // THis line is main Part this is returned by checkForm() function
    }

// If I am still not clear, then I'll be happy to explain it on Google Meet.! :)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Could you explain what you've changed, was the OP doing something wrong?